# Is there a way to test an M10 Atlas cluster on MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

We have an M10 cluster and the official page states that we get a max of 100 IOPS.

I cant run mongoperf on the cluster as we have direct mongo shell and compass access and mongoperf needs to be run on the instance that has MongoDB installed.

Is there any way to test the maximum requests per second that this cluster can handle and if not, is there any rough estimate available as to how many read/write operations it can handle concurrently?

PS:- Assume the queries being run aren't particularly complex and are only entering small sets of data such as Name, Email Address, Age, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to test the maximum requests per second that this cluster can handle and if not, is there any rough estimate available as to how many read/write operations it can handle concurrently?

The answer to this, really depends on a lot of variables. i.e. document sizes, indexes utilisation, network latency between application and servers, etc.

To provide a rough estimation however, assuming your MongoDB cluster is hosted on [AWS](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/aws-mongodb) (GCP and Azure would be different), the specs would be:

M10, 2GB RAM and 10GB included storage.

In addition to this, you can select different EBS storage sizes as well as provisioned IOPS to match your required performance.

See also [MongoDB Atlas: FAQ](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/faq)

> We have an M10 cluster and the official page states that we get a max of 100 IOPS.

The number of IOPS advertised is, what would be advised by the cloud provider, i.e. AWS. Not taking account the network latency and your database usage that affects the server resources i.e. CPU/RAM.